# What are "Entity" and "Controller" in an OOP programed project

Tags: oop, entity

It may sound stupid. And please, redirect me if there is a similar question asked.
But in big projects I often see Classes named Entity or "Controller". Can someone explane to me what are they used for (generally)? Can you provide some examples aswell.
I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple sense:

An entity represents data, for example you may have a Car Entity.

A controller, typically, routes data: "controls" where it goes.